# How can I route specific domain names to a specific server

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, routing, windows-sbs, router

We have 3 servers internally.
- The first one (*beluga*) is our domain controller and file server. It has a DNS controller, but I don't know how to configure it correctly, and my boss don't want us to touch it (it created some problems a while ago). It runs on Windows 2003 Small Business Server.
- The second one (*baleine*) is an internal web server, with IIS6 and SQL Server. It runs on Windows 2003 Standard.
- The third one (*dauphin*) is our brand new internal web server, set to unload our previous one, which is starting to be impossibly slow. It runs on Windows 2008 R2 Standard.

Let's assume our company's domain name is cp.com.
In order to test our web sites on our production servers, we configured the DNS server for cp.com, so that when we type anything.*servername*.cp.com, it redirects the request to the correct server.
In other words, *.*servername*.cp.com redirects to the IP address of *servername*, and then we configure each IIS site's "identity" (on IIS6, "binding" on IIS7) so the right one shows.

We want to do the same with our local servers. We already have *.local.cp.com which redirects to our public IP, and our router redirects all port 80 requests to baleine.

Ideally, we would type clientname.*servername*.local.cp.com, and it would redirect to the right server. We have a Netgear WRT54G routeur, with a DD-WRT ROM, which provides some DNS capabilities through something called "DNSMasq". Can I configure it so it routes a specific domain name request to a specific server ?

Or maybe our second server could publicly expose its IP address, but I don't even know if it's possible. If it is, I really don't know how to set it up. Is it possible with a standard DSL connection ?

There may be other solutions I'm not aware of...

What would you do, or better yet, what did you do when you faced the same problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use just create another zone called clientname.local.cp.com in your internal DNS and add records appropriately? That's from inside. Do you require same availability from the INTERNET?

Comment: Firstly, I don't understand what you mean by creating zones and adding records, I don't know much about DNS routing. Secondly, yes, we need the sites to be available outside, so our clients can see them. Thanks.

Comment: Navigate to Administrative Tools on your server and open DNS Manager. Expand the existing forward-lookup zones, you'll see your internal zone there. Just a create a new forward lookup zone, you'll be able to add records to the zone specifying the name of the server where it will be located.

Comment: Ok, but for that to work, I need the computers to have the Windows server as primary DNS, right ?

Comment: That's correct, first it will allow you to control name resolution, second will reduce latency on DNS requests since all the queries will be sent to local computer.

Comment: Thanks, but my boss is very reluctant to change DNS tables in Windows SBS (he basically said "I will never touch *that* again"). He showed me that DD-WRT seems to have (at least) basic DNS capabilities, I will try to find something in that way. Thanks anyway ;)